# How to run an animation before scrollView ends deceleration?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift4

I have an app where I have a collection view. I have an extension for the collection view of a UIScrollView, in order to detect when the user has swiped a certain amount to the right. I Succesful do this, but then want to animate (UIView.Animate) an image to alpha 1.0 (from 0.0) before the cells come back to their original spots (well, right after you let go from scrolling...). My issue is that it does not animate until ending the deceleration of the drag...

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if let _ = scrollView as? UICollectionView {

        if shouldAction {                

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 1.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {

                    self.peformAction.alpha = 1.0

                })

            fetchMessageFromFirebase {
                reloadMessage.isHidden = true
            }

        }

    }

}
```

UPDATE:

Yes, I also have tried other methods, for example, scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating

Comment: Add a completion block to your animation and put the `reloadContentFromFirebase { reloadImage.isHidden = true }` in the completion block

Comment: @Adrian I tried this but still did not work. I think the problem is with the scrollViewDidDecelerating, I tried the animation without the firebase function, and it still performs it only once the scrollView has ended decelerating.

Comment: Isn't the function didEndDecelerating suggests that this will be called after the deceleration has ended? Shouldn't you be using scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619386-scrollviewwillbegindecelerating

Comment: @kerry yes I am aware of that, I have checked several other of the methods, even the one u suggested, yet all of them have the same effect :(

Comment: I just tried in an example. Have a look at this https://pastebin.com/sFvGcSCT
This has view controller file code and main.storyboard code. Put this in a sample single view project and you will get the expected behaviour.